# How can I check if a file has finished uploading before moving it with the Google Drive API v3?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm writing a small archiving script (in node.js) to move files on my Google Drive to a predetermined folder if they contain `.archive.7z` in the filename. The script is run periodically as a cron job, and the file movement has not caused any issues, but files still in the process of being uploaded by my desktop client are moved before they're finished. This terminates the upload and results in corrupted files in the destination folder.

Files still being uploaded from my desktop to Google Drive are returned by the following function anyway:

```
async function getArchivedFiles (drive) {
  const res = await drive.files.list({
    q: "name contains '.archive.7z'",
    fields: 'files(id, name, parents)',
  })

  return res.data.files
}
```

Once the files are moved and renamed with the following code, the upload terminates from my client (Insync) and the destination files are ruined.

```
drive.files.update({
  fileId: file.id,
  addParents: folderId,
  removeParents: previousParents,
  fields: 'id, parents',
  requestBody: {
    name: renameFile(file.name)
  }
})
```

Is there any way to check if a file is still being uploaded before moving it?

Comment: Why don't you add to your upload function into an `await` operator and list files only once the promise has been fulfilled?

Comment: The uploads are being carried out from a separate source, unfortunately. The client doing the uploading and the script moving the archive files are two separate applications running from two separate machines, with no communication between them. The former is a desktop app running on my laptop, and the archive script is running periodically off a Digital Ocean Droplet.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that a tiny placeholder-type file is being created on uploads. I'm not sure if this is a Google Drive API behaviour or something unique to the Insync desktop client. This file seems to upload separately and thus can be freely renamed once it's complete.

I worked around this problem by including the file's md5 hash in the filename, and updating my script to only move files when the hash in their filename matches the `md5Checksum` retrieved from the Google Drive API.